# Google Analytics API - inconsistent data

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have a couple of problems with Google Analytics API.

1. Certain data pulled from the API is changing retroactively - especially the number of "not set" sessions.  The data I pulled last month no longer matches with the data returned by the API (for the same query, profile and dates).  For instance, last month I got 120 "not set" sessions and now I am getting 1930 "not set" sessions.
2. There is a dramatic increase in the number of "not set" sessions.  This affects historical dates as well.

So it looks like the historical data was modified - specifically all the data > August 2013.

I also noticed the overall number of sessions (total number of sessions for all metros) stays the same.  However the "not set" sessions is way much bigger and then almost each metro has less sessions (somehow the attribution changed but I have no idea how and why).

Any idea what is causing these discrepancies?

Let me give you an example.
My query returns the metros and the sessions in the United States.
[here is a screenshot containing some of my results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzWhW.png)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's relative, but did you try to disable sampling in Analytic's interface (move slider in the right upper corner)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am pulling data day by day so there is no sampling.  I was thinking about a spam issue... any idea how to contact Google?

Comment: his question is about the API.  It is not possible to disable sampling in the core reporting API.  Unless you have a premium account and then you use unsampled reports.   either way this does not answer the question because you are talking about the website and he is talking about the API.   the two are unrelated.